# EventLog access is not supported on this platform when calling dependency from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, event-log

I am trying to create an azure function (v2) but it needs to reference an existing class library which is built for .netframework and is currently used for a .net web project.  In the referenced library a lot of code is wrapped in try / catches where we log the exception to the EventLog.

My question is, how can I make it so that the referenced library handles the EventLog code or is this something that is not possible?

I have tried calling event log directly from a simple function (i.e. EventLog.WriteEntry(...) but that causes the same error: EventLog access is not supported on this platform.   I take it, this is because its expecting me to use the built in ILogger instance to perform the logging...

I've read that we can add the Nuget package for compatibility and also one for EventLog.  Tried both and still no luck...